# Why browser doesn't cache java script(Ajax)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have made a cascade drop down list box using jquery. user selects state from first drop down and according to selected state the second drop down will fll by appropriate cities.
my problem is about caching of second drop down. when user clicks on back browser button and then click on forward button the city drop down contents is empty.
Is there any way to tell browser cache the data?

Comment: If the data's small can you store it in a cookie?

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea. but I'm looking for the other method.

Answer (score 0):

It's HTTP, so you'll have to find a way to set the caching and last modified headers when you make the AJAX request.  It'll also help to add it to the DOM when you make the request, that way it's available to the second drop-down.